# comparing two strings with "-" hyphen in bash

Tags: string, bash, compare

I'm trying to compare two strings that contain **"-"** in them , for example:

```
if [[ "–change_team" == "${Args[2]}" ]]; then
```

where "${Args[2]}" is "–change_team"

I tried to print "–change_team" like this :

```
echo "–change_team"
```

and I got is :

```
âchange_team
```

the if statement never gives success , and I've tried escaping with "" it didn't go well for me.

Comment: The character may not be a hyphen. There are a few different 8-bit graphic characters that look like hyphens but, depending upon what set is being displayed, won't show as such. What do you see for `echo "-change_team" | od -c` versus `echo "${Args[2]}" | od -c`?

Comment: it prints:
0000000   -   c   h   a   n   g   e   _   t   e   a   m  \n
0000015
=========================
0000000   -   c   h   a   n   g   e   _   t   e   a   m  \n
0000015

Comment: That doesn't match what I got. When I used the string you show in your problem statement (copied "–change_team" and did `echo "–change_team" | od -c`) I get: `0000000 342 200 223   c   h   a   n   g   e   _   t   e   a   m  \n`. So the one you are showing in your problem statement isn't a hyphen character.

Comment: does this have any thing to do with my ssh server ? (college)
to be honest i thought that hyphen is just another name for "-" i didn't know there is a difference.

Comment: Check the hyphen character you're using in front of the "change_team" string in `if [[ "–change_team" == "${Args[2]}" ]]; then`. I don't think that's a hyphen. Edit the script, delete the `–` and try retyping a "real" hyphen.

Comment: Please note comparing strings that way with a *real* hyphen is tricky because hyphen starts "test" boolean operators. So when you solve the current problem you should change it to something like `[[ x-change_team" == "x${Args[2]}" ]]`, otherwise test will spontaneously fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different 8-bit graphic characters that may look like a hyphen depending upon the character being used for the user interface. In the case of your `if` statement:

```
if [[ "–change_team" == "${Args[2]}" ]]; then
```

If I copy your "–change_team" string and use it here:

```
echo "–change_team" | od -c
```

I get this result:

```
0000000 342 200 223   c   h   a   n   g   e   _   t   e   a   m  \n
0000017
```

If it were a real hyphen, you'd get:

```
0000000 -   c   h   a   n   g   e   _   t   e   a   m  \n
0000017
```

So in the original script, the "hyphen" character being used in the comparison isn't a proper hyphen.

Comment: thank you very much , it appears that when i copy "–change_team" from the PDF it copies as hyphen,and i was comparing to normal dash "-".

Comment: @Emad4U Yes, it's a little risky copying straight from PDF since Adobe will use a font/character of their choosing to represent, for example, a hyphen. I'm glad you have it all sorted. :)